# Scheme: Accelerated Stream

Tags: scheme, sicp

From this example code I found online, which functions are the unaccelerated stream, the singly-accelrated stream, and the super-accelerated stream? Thank you in advance.

Cite: lawfulsamurai.blogspot.com/2009/01/sicp-section-35-streams.html

```
(define (log2-summands n)  
  (cons-stream (/ 1.0 n)  
           (stream-map - (log2-summands (+ n 1))))) 

(define log2-stream   
 (partial-sums (log2-summands 1))) 

(define log2-stream-euler   
  (euler-transform log2-stream))  

(define log2-stream-accelerated  
  (accelerated-sequence euler-transform log2-stream))
```

Comment: I think your code came from either http://wqzhang.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/sicp-exercise-3-65/ or http://lawfulsamurai.blogspot.com/2009/01/sicp-section-35-streams.html. Note that it's important to attribute the source of any code you post.

Comment: Sorry about that. Next time I will cite examples

Comment: @King1 There's an "Edit" button under your question.  You should cite examples not just next time, but this time too, *in the question* (since comments can be deleted without record at any time.  Otherwise your question is likely to be deleted as plagiarism.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor/Chris Jester-Young, Do either of you know the answer now that I've cited the code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be answered directly in the blog post that OP cited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you didn't tell us what either a "singly-accelrated" or  "super-accelerated" *are*, so it's hard to say where in the code they are.  It's like playing "Where's Waldo", but without knowing what a "Waldo" is.

That said, I can see that log2-summands, euler-transform, make-tableau, and accelerated-sequence all return streams, so it seems like they'd be the candidates.  Now, if we actually look at the blog post that you linked to, [SICP Section 3.5 Streams](http://lawfulsamurai.blogspot.com/2009/01/sicp-section-35-streams.html), we read:

> 1. Straightforward summation using partial-sums. The value of log2 oscillates between 0.6687714031754279 and 0.7163904507944756 after 20
>      iterations.
>
>    ```
>    (define log2-stream   
>      (partial-sums (log2-summands 1)))
>    ```
> 2. Log2 using Euler Transformation. Value converges to 0.6932106782106783 after 10 iterations.
>
>    ```
>    (define log2-stream-euler   
>      (euler-transform log2-stream))
>    ```
> 3. Accelerated summation. Value converges to 0.6931488693329254 in 4 iterations.
>
>    ```
>    (define log2-stream-accelerated  
>      (accelerated-sequence euler-transform log2-stream))
>    ```

It sounds like that the **log2-stream**, **log2-stream-euler**, and **log2-stream-accelerated** are, respectively, the "unaccelerated stream, the singly-accelrated stream, and the super-accelerated stream".